# How to convert my game to a newer version?

Tags: game-engine

I want to get 2.74, but my game is in 2.72. How can I convert this safely, meaning that **everything will stay as is, except new features will be possible.**?

Comment: I don't think there is any official conversion script or anything.. I think the best you can do is keep a close eye on the release notes and compensate for API changes manually

Comment: I'd do what I do. Download 2.74 but keep the version you're currently using. Duplicate the file and open that one up in 2.74. From there just examine your project to see if there are any changes to your project. If there are and you can't find a solution, just use 2.72 until there is. :)

Comment: Honestly, i had one that i was worried about, but i just opened it up into 2.74 and it still looks fine. don't sweat it, no changes willl be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the the most recent version of blender or the version of blender of your choice and simply run the file. Blender doesn't necessarily convert files except for the fact that you can import/export them. Right now i am running Blender v2.74.5 and if I want to use a 2.6x blender file I can the only thing that will probably be different is the interface differences. So you may not have any idea how/what they set the settings/options to.

Comment: That's not exactly true. There was a slight backwards compatibility breakage in the upgrade from 2.69 to 2.7; as a result, some files may file to load, or load incorrectly.